# jQuery wont return the reference of a simple canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple initialization function, that creates a canvas element in the body and should save its reference in a variable.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong but jQuery doesn't want to return the reference :(

I tried to reference other html elements like the body but this also didn't work.

Strange is that if I execute `$('#Gravity_Canvas')` in the chrome debuger it gives me the reference.

Here is the code:

```
function Gravity() {
    this.containerRef = null;
    this.objGroups = null;
    this.objects = new Array();

    init();

    function init() {
        $('body').append('<canvas id="Gravity_Canvas" width="' + window.innerWidth + '" height="' + window.innerHeight + '"> </canvas>');
        this.containerRef = $('#Gravity_Canvas'); // Here is the problem

        this.objGroups = { 'default': new ObjectGroup() };
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So then `this.containerRef` is an empty jquery object?

Comment: No at first it has the value null. Then in the init function, a reference to the canvas element should be saved in it. So it's never an empty jQuery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like below. Notice I have introduced a "that" variable! This is because **this** inside init() does not refer to the same object as **this** inside Gravity().

```
function Gravity() {
    var that = this;
    that.containerRef = null;
    that.objGroups = null;
    that.objects = new Array();

    init();

    function init() {
        that.containerRef = $('<canvas id="Gravity_Canvas" width="' + window.innerWidth + '" height="' + window.innerHeight + '"> </canvas>');
        $('body').append(that.containerRef);

        that.objGroups = { 'default': new ObjectGroup() };
    }
}
```